# ASP.NET MVC 3 and HTML Helper Extensions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to work out whether I am misunderstanding something about ASP.NET MVC or whether I have found some sort of bug in ASP.NET MVC Beta 3. I am having a problem with a PartialView picking up the wrong model when using HTML Helper extensions

My controller code looks like this:

```
public ActionResult EditGeneral(MapGeneralViewModel vm)
{
    var query = MapGeneralViewModel.ToModel(vm, svcMaps);

    return PartialView("General", MapGeneralViewModel.FromModel(query));
}
```

In the case of this being an insert, the property **vm.Id** starts out as -1 and after the call to **MapGeneralViewModel.ToModel** it has been persisted the database and query.Id has a proper value.

The call to **MapSettingsViewModel.FromModel** returns a new viewmodel and I have checked that the Id property correct contains the newly created id value.

The relevant bits of the view look like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AdminWebRole.Models.Map.MapGeneralViewModel>" %>
            <%: Model.Id %>
            <%= Html.Hidden("IdTest", Model.Id) %>
            <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id) %>
```

If I put a breakpoint in the view, **Model.Id** is correctly set to the right value.

The actual output of the controller (when **Model.Id** == 70) looks like this:

```
    70
    <input id="IdTest" name="IdTest" type="hidden" value="-1" />
    <input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="-1" />
```

So the value output without using the HTML helpers is correct, but the values output by the helpers somehow is picking up the viewmodel that was passed into the controller !

I have no idea how this is happening. I have tried various things:

- Using **View()** rather than **PartialView()**
- assigning the results of **MapGeneralViewModel.FromModel()** to **vm** and then passing **vm** to the view
- using **<%:** and **<%=**
- setting **vm** to null (the old view model somehow still gets used)
- changing the value of the incoming id to 0 (results in 0 being output in the view instead of -1)
- the problem isn't specific to properties called "Id", I have also tested other fields with the same result

Am I confused over how this is supposed to work or have I hit a beta bug ? If it makes any difference, this is running inside my local Azure runtime on a Win7 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that MVC is just picking up a variable that you haven't explicitly passed to your view or have hanging around in Session or TempData.

Since you're setting that Id to -1 I'm start there for problems.

The other possibility is that -1 is hanging around in your ModelState someplace.  The HTML helpers look to ModelState first before deciding to use any values you pass in.

Comment: It does seem to be coming from the ModelState. Reading around it seems I have to not use HTML Helpers for properties on the model that have changed since being posted tom the Controller. In this case that will be just the Id property. Does that make sense ?

Comment: @andynormancx, yeah, the ModelState greedy HtmlHelpers bite everybody it seems.

Comment: If this is by design that would be really depressing! Have you figured out what going on or are we actually supposed to make 2 trips to the db in order to get auto generated id, or query modelstate directly if we don't want to do that?

Comment: Just to add I remember my id field wasn't being updated in mvc and I had to make another trip to get it so had the same problem as you did.

Comment: I didn't have to make a round trip to the database, I just had to use my own code to emit the id field from my model as it came back from the database. I suspect I still don't understand how you are supposed to use the model binding and ModelState fully, need to sit down and get to the bottom of it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I have just come across a similar issue in a partial view that I use for displaying the items in an order.

I was using the following to render a hidden input.

`@Html.Hidden("salesorderlineid", orderLine.SalesOrderLineID)`

This works fine until I delete an item, when the ID of the wrong (deleted) item is used. I double-checked the model, this was correct and rendered correctly in other usages on the same view.

I coded the hidden input directly as html and it works fine - looks like an MVC3 bug perhaps?

`<input type="hidden" name="salesorderlineid" value="@orderLine.SalesOrderLineID"/>`